# Checking if text boxes are empty

Tags: vb.net, winforms, textbox

I have a winform with a bound datagridview, 4 text boxes and a button. With the click of the button the "fillby" statement is called, the data is loaded on the datagridview and the content of the text boxes become the default value of some fields in the new rows of the datagridview.

I need to check all the text boxes to make sure they're not empty, if any of them is empty then a message should pop up saying which text box is empty and also keeps the datagridview from filling.

This is the code I have so far:

```
 Private Sub btnCargarInformacion_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnCargar.Click
    Dim emptyTextBoxes =
    From txt In Me.Controls.OfType(Of TextBox)()
    Where txt.Text.Length = 0
    Select txt.Name

    If emptyTextBoxes.Count >= -1 Then
        MessageBox.Show(String.Format("Please fill following textboxes: {0}", String.Join(",", emptyTextBoxes)))
    Else
        Dim PartePersonalTableApt As New PersonalObraDataSetTableAdapters.PartePersonalTableAdapter
        Dim PersonalObTableApt As New PersonalObraDataSetTableAdapters.PersonalObTableAdapter
        PartePersonalTableApt.ClearBeforeFill = True
        PartePersonalTableApt.FillByFecha(PersonalObraDataSet.PartePersonal, txtDate.Text, txtDepartamento.Text, txtTurno.Text)
        PersonalObTableApt.ClearBeforeFill = True
        PersonalObTableApt.Fillby(PersonalObraDataSet.PersonalOb)
    End If
End Sub
```

I don't get any errors, the message appears even if all textboxes are filled, the message box does not specifying any text boxes as empty  and stops the datagridview from filling.

I'm very new to codding so please explain in more detail your solution. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try to loop at your **container** (ie form, panel, groupbox) for each textbox without content, then increment whenever there is a textbox that doesn't have content.

Example:

```
          Dim checkr as integer = 0
          Dim this As Control
          For Each this In that.Controls
           If TypeOf this Is TextBox Then
               If this.text = "" then
                 Checkr += 1
               End if
             End If
           Next

           If checkr > 0 then
              msgbox("Cannot proceed because a textbox has no content")
           Else
              '......(what you were gonna do)
           End If
```

Answer (score 2):

```
.Count >= -1
```

The count will be 0 if it's empty

```
If emptyTextBoxes.Count <> 0 Then
    MessageBox.Show(String.Format("Please fill following textboxes: {0}", String.Join(",", emptyTextBoxes)))
Else
    Dim PartePersonalTableApt As New PersonalObraDataSetTableAdapters.PartePersonalTableAdapter
    Dim PersonalObTableApt As New PersonalObraDataSetTableAdapters.PersonalObTableAdapter
    PartePersonalTableApt.ClearBeforeFill = True
    PartePersonalTableApt.FillByFecha(PersonalObraDataSet.PartePersonal, txtDate.Text, txtDepartamento.Text, txtTurno.Text)
    PersonalObTableApt.ClearBeforeFill = True
    PersonalObTableApt.Fillby(PersonalObraDataSet.PersonalOb)
End If
```

Comment: That doesn't fix it. No errors, but no messagebox either regardless of empty or filled texboxes. Thanks

Comment: @David - TextBox Controls don't seem to have a .Name property perhaps you meant to use Select txt.ID

Comment: I might be wrong, but all controls should have a Name property. ID is not an option visual studio's intelisense suggests. I might be wrong though.

Comment: @David - sorry about that I was looking at System.Web.UI controls instead of System.Windows.Forms controls. You'll just have to run your code through the debugger and inspect the "emptyTextBoxes" enumerable you could convert it to an array first with ToArray method.

Comment: Like  I said i'm very new to codding in general, so that answer doesn't really help me much. I would really need a more detailed answer with some example code if possible.